# Does our perception of what $a$ is in these two expression's change?

Tags: abstract-algebra, soft-question, terminology

Take the polynomial $f(x) = x^2 + ax + 2$ we might think of $a$ as being a paramter (arbitrary constant) and $x$ being a variable. This means, we choose a value of $a$ then we vary $x$ to get the outputs of $f$. If we wish to find the discriminant $d$, we will use the formula $b^2 - 4ac$ to get $a^2 - 8$, which is a function of $a$, $d(a) = a^2 -8$, what should we call $a$ in the expression for $d$? Is it a variable now? Initally we had $x$ and $a$, and $x$ was "more important" so we gave $a$ the name of a parameter, rather than a variable (it is still kind of a special variable). In $d$ there is no $x$'s.

Comment: Perhaps just avoid using the terms “parameter” and “variable” entirely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Honestly the whole notion of what parameters are fixed, and what are variable is arbitrary.

The idea of $x$ being more important than $a$ is really something we impose as people.

Basically we choose what is fixed and what is not. Math does not care if that makes sense.

In the expression for $d=a^2-8$, $a$ could be fixed or variable depending on what we decide, OR what the question maker decides

Comment: lol I accidently posted it too early with a misclick. fixing it now

Comment: I am thinking that all we are told is $a \in \mathbb{R}$, and in that case we want to find which range of $a$ makes $f$ have no real roots. In that case, we think of $d$ as being a function of $a$ ( a variable) right? But then when we put $a$ back into the quadratic, $x$ is the "variable" and $a$ is fixed for this specific $f$.

Comment: Indeed that is correct. In the context of trying to find where the quadratic has no real roots, You would think of $d$ as a function of $a$, and call $a$ a variable.

If I gave you a question where I said solve $x^2+ax+2 = 0$ where $a\in\mathbb{R}$ is fixed. Then you would call $a$ a fixed parameter. We have the power to decide

Comment: Even then, saying $a$ is fixed just means that its not varying (yet its completely arbitrary, it doesn't have $1$ value, it could be any real!). The roots would be in terms of $a$, then we could write $x_1(a)$ and $x_2(a)$..... Where $a$ is back to variable.

Comment: You see how arbitrary all is. IT really is what we decide. You could say $a$ doesn't change but whO's stopping you ya know. As you do more math through out your life it will become mORe clear

Comment: We can't really call anything fixed in place until its a number like $1$ or $10^{2332}$, maths basically varies everything without us wanting to or not, then we put restrictions in.

Answer (score 3):

Using the synthetic notation of polynomials might help. Given a triple of numbers (ordered) such as $(2,-3,8)$ one can associate a function $\mathbf R \to \mathbf R$ by defining it as  sending $x\mapsto 2x^2-3x+8$.

That is, a general triple of numbers $(r,s,t)$ represents the polynomial function $rx^2+sx+t$.

A specific triple (with first entry non-zero)  gives rise to a single quadratic polynomial function. Now let us reformulate your polynomial in this triple notation  $(1,a,2)$ is  a **collection** of quadratic  polynomial functions one for each choice of $a$.

Now discriminant is a function from the *set of all quadratic polynomials* to  the set of real numbers.  For  a polynomial presented as  the  triple $(r,s,t)$ its discriminant is  defined to be $s^2-4rt$.

So, for a function, a general element of its domain may be called a variable, and the formula (if one is available) defining the function will be in terms of the variable.

When we consider *a set of functions* and if there is a formula that describes all the elements of the set, the variable that describes them is called a parameter.

The function $f(x,y) = x^2+y^2-5$ is a function from the set of points on the plane to the set of real numbers. Instead we can consider the set of all functions, $x^2+y^2-3, x^2+y^2-8, x^2-y^2-186.47$ etc. That is the collection of functions $x^2+y^2-a$ where $a$ is a positive real number. Each of them is a function and $a$ is a parameter.

Now for the function $x^2+y^2-a$ I can associate the  real number $+\sqrt a$ as the radius (of the circle represented by) the function $x^2+y^2-a=0$ (analogous  with the discriminant).